# pow() seems to be out by one here

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-precision, pow

What's going on here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("17^12 = %lf\n", pow(17, 12));
    printf("17^13 = %lf\n", pow(17, 13));
    printf("17^14 = %lf\n", pow(17, 14));
}
```

I get this output:

```
17^12 = 582622237229761.000000
17^13 = 9904578032905936.000000
17^14 = 168377826559400928.000000
```

13 and 14 do not match with [wolfram alpa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=17%5E12,%2017%5E13,%2017%5E14) cf:

```
12: 582622237229761.000000
    582622237229761

13: 9904578032905936.000000
    9904578032905937

14: 168377826559400928.000000
    168377826559400929
```

Moreover, it's not wrong by some strange fraction - it's wrong by exactly one!

If this is down to me reaching the limits of what `pow()` can do for me, is there an alternative that can calculate this?  I need a function that can calculate `x^y`, where `x^y` is always less than ULLONG_MAX.

Comment: Maybe you need to know [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

Comment: Fun fact: this loop does not terminate: `for (float f = 0; f < INT_MAX; f++) { }`

Comment: The `l` in `%lf` does not do anything. You are printing `double`s, and if your compilation platforms maps `double` to IEEE 754's double-precision format, you will never print `9904578032905937.0` this way, as there is no such double-precision number.

Comment: @ntoskrnl: _might_ not terminate. It did on Crays and systems where `int` was 16 bits.

Comment: With a `double`, you can always rely on the first 15 decimal digits (significant digits). With `17**12`, that is all the digits until the point. With `17**13`, you can not trust the last digit. That `double` would normally (with no formatting) be written as `9.90457803290594E+15`. And `17**14` with that notation is `1.68377826559401E+17`.

Comment: Presumably wolfram etc. are using "big int" or "infinite precision integer" math to calculate this, rather than (as pow does), convert your arguments to doubles, and do an `exp(b*ln a)` type operation.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen  "With a double, you can always rely on the first 15 decimal digits" is not supported by the C spec nor my experience.  C specification is a minimum of 9 or 10 digits depending on semantics.  C11dr 5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types.  You may be referencing IEEE 754.

Comment: Using floating-point arithmetic for exact integer computations is cringeworthy.

Comment: @chux Yes, I was referring to an IEEE 754 [double-precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) number, and that is a specific 64-bit floating point format. I see that the C specification [allows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) the C keyword `double` to represent other formats. What implementation of C do you use? It is clear that the C implementation of trideceth12 uses IEEE double-precision.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen For `double` I've used 1) IEEE 754 compliant, 2) not-so IEEE 754 compliant 3) `float` & `double` are the same 32-bit 4) variants of IEEE 754 with no NAN nor INF nor denormals 5) A _decimal_ FP.  It changes from project to project.  The key is that C itself is not as constrained as the 15 decimal digits assertion and robust code accounts for platform variation.

Comment: @Prateek: Nothing wrong with it.  Certainly nothing "cringeworthy" about it at all.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`pow` works with `double` numbers. These represent numbers of the form s * 2^e where s is a 53 bit integer. Therefore `double` can store all integers below 2^53, but only *some* integers above 2^53. In particular, it can only represent even numbers > 2^53, since for e > 0 the value is always a multiple of 2.

17^13 needs 54 bits to represent exactly, so e is set to 1 and hence the calculated value becomes even number. The correct value is odd, so it's not surprising it's off by one. Likewise, 17^14 takes 58 bits to represent. That it too is off by one is a lucky coincidence (as long as you don't apply too much number theory), it just happens to be one off from a *multiple of 32*, which is the granularity at which `double` numbers of that magnitude are rounded.

For exact integer exponentiation, you should use integers all the way. Write your own `double`-free exponentiation routine. Use exponentiation by squaring if `y` can be large, but I assume it's always less than 64, making this issue moot.

Comment: okay I don't want to reinvent the wheel here though.. especially as I need this not to be unnecessarily slow.. is there an obvious way I should be doing this (other than `for i ... y: result *=x`)

Comment: @trideceth12 That is the obvious way you should be doing. And it's too simple to constitute reinventing the wheel. Given that you're constrained into the range of a 64 bit integer and `x` and `y` are integers, there are neither precision issues to solve nor big performance challenges that call for sophisticated algorithms (10, 20 or even 60 multiplications are cheap, cheaper than any I/O for example).

Comment: A bit of modular arithmetic: 17 % 16 = 1, so 17^n % 16 = 1 (meaning the four least significant bits in the binary representation of 17^n will always be 0001).

Comment: @tom That's what I meant by applying too much number theory +1 Though it's not a full explanation, as it needs to be 1 (as opposed to 17) modulo 32 to be off by one. There probably isn't much of a pattern though, 17^15 is more-than-one off.

Comment: @delnan I missed 17^14 having five truncated bits. But 17^2 % 32 = 1, so 17^14 % 32 = (17^2)^7 % 32 = 1.

Comment: @trideceth12 There is the square-and-multiply algo which has runtime logarithmic in the exponent instead of linear.

Answer (score 14):

The numbers you get are too big to be represented with a `double` accurately. A double-precision floating-point number has essentially 53 significant binary digits and can represent all integers up to `2^53` or 9,007,199,254,740,992.

For higher numbers, the last digits get truncated and the result of your calculation is rounded to the next number that can be represented as a `double`. For `17^13`, which is only slightly above the limit, this is the closest even number. For numbers greater than `2^54` this is the closest number that is divisible by four, and so on.

Comment: Ahh.. the closest even number makes sense

Answer (score 14):

If your input arguments are non-negative integers, then you can implement your own `pow`.

**Recursively:**

```
unsigned long long pow(unsigned long long x,unsigned int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
        return 1;
    if (y == 1)
        return x;
    return pow(x,y/2)*pow(x,y-y/2);
}
```

**Iteratively:**

```
unsigned long long pow(unsigned long long x,unsigned int y)
{
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while (y--)
        res *= x;
    return res;
}
```

**Efficiently:**

```
unsigned long long pow(unsigned long long x,unsigned int y)
{
    unsigned long long res = 1;
    while (y > 0)
    {
        if (y & 1)
            res *= x;
        y >>= 1;
        x *= x;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The recursive version is useless because it doesn't reuse the answer. One recursive call is sufficient: `root = y ? pow(x, y / 2) : 1; return root * root * (y&1 ? x : 1);`

Comment: @chux: Just noticed that missing `if (y == 1)`... I can't believe it's been there for so long without me noticing it. Thanks a lot!!!!! :)

Comment: @tom  Right you are.  Missed the "eventually multiplies by pow(0, 1)".

Answer (score 2):

A small addition to other good answers: under x86 architecture there is usually available [x87 80-bit extended format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision), which is supported by most C compilers via the [`long double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) type. This format allows to operate with integer numbers up to `2^64` without gaps.

There is analogue of `pow()` in `<math.h>` which is intended for operating with `long double` numbers - `powl()`. It should also be noticed that the format specifier for the `long double` values is other than for `double` ones - `%Lf`. So the correct program using the `long double` type looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("17^12 = %Lf\n", powl(17, 12));
    printf("17^13 = %Lf\n", powl(17, 13));
    printf("17^14 = %Lf\n", powl(17, 14));
}
```

As Stephen Canon noted in comments there is no guarantee that this program should give exact result.

Comment: (a) The length modifier for `long double` is `L`, not `ll`.  (b) There’s no guarantee that `powl` delivers a sub-ulp accurate result (which is necessary for this to give the “right” answer); on some platforms it doesn’t.

Comment: @StephenCanon (a) `llf` is nonstandard variant, it is my error, thank you. (b) Of course you are right, but I didn't write that this program would give correct results.

Comment: I'd even point out that `powl` gives wildly wrong results on many implementations.

Comment: @tmyklebu Even if CPU supports x87 instruction set?

Comment: Yeah, especially if it's an x87.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. I have a reasonably extensive unit testing suite (which is what turned up the original problem), So It's good to have another option - and if it passes my tests it works perfectly every time for every possible input, right? ;)