# Inaccuracy when using pow() function

Tags: c, numbers

I made a program that splits a number into numbers that, when added, give the first number. For example, 1234 should be split into 1000, 200, 30, and 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
int i, num1, num2;
char tmp[6];  // the number will be stored here as string
int num3 = 12345;  //the number 

sprintf(tmp, "%d", num3); //convert to string
for(i = 0; i < strlen(tmp); i++)  //check every digit
{
    num1 = pow(10, strlen(tmp) - 1 - i);  //every number will be multiplied by 10
                           //to the power of number of digits - 1 - counter
    num2 = tmp[i] - '0';   //convert character to int
    printf("%d\n", num1*num2); //print the number
}

 return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
9999
2000
297
40
5
```

As you can see this is not correct, why?

Comment: Your posted version seems to work as is http://ideone.com/K3pY8r

Comment: Because `pow` includes a floating-point representation error.

Comment: I tried it on multiple online compilers and it does work, but it doesn't work on my PC.How do I avoid that error?

Comment: Don't use floating point if you need exact values.

Comment: So why does this error appear and how do I remove the floating point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pow() seems to be out by one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452711/pow-seems-to-be-out-by-one-here)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that floating point calculations may have small errors. Which is to say that the results of the `pow` function may be slightly larger or slightly smaller than expected. When you convert to an `int`, the result is truncated. For example, if `pow(10,4)` returns `9999.999999`, then converting to an `int` yields `9999`, which is not what you expected. On the other hand, if `pow(10,3)` returns `1000.000001` then converting to an `int` will give the expected result.

Here's some code that should demonstrate the problem (on computers where the results of the `pow` function are not exact):

```
int main( void )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        double num1 = pow(10,i);
        int num2 = num1;
        printf( "%12f --> %5d\n", num1, num2 );
    }
}
```

To avoid the problem, you either need to round the results of `pow`, or avoid floating point math altogether. Here's some code that shows how to solve the problem using only integer math.

```
int main( void )
{
    char temp[] = "12345";
    int length = strlen( temp );

    int multiplier = 1;
    for ( int i = 1; i < length; i++ )
        multiplier *= 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        printf( "%d\n", (temp[i] - '0') * multiplier );
        multiplier /= 10;
    }
}
```