# C reverse a number recursivly

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I have an assigment to create a function that recieves a number, and return the reversed number.

E.G :

```
Input : 12343 
Output : 34321
```

No loops allowed, and the input is only the number .

This is what I've tried :

```
long GetReverse(unsigned long n)
{
    if (n < 10)
        return n % 10;
    else
        return  10 * GetReverse(n / 10) + n % 10;
}
```

Though This is retuning me the same input and not reversing the number ( I know what is the problem here, I just can't think of a way to do it)

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** This is the solution I came up with :

```
int numOfMulti(unsigned long num) {
    if (num < 10)
        return 1;
    return 10 * numOfMulti(num / 10); 
}

long GetReverse(unsigned long n)
{
    if (n < 10)
        return n % 10; 
    else
        return  n % 10 * numOfMulti(n) + GetReverse(n / 10) ; 
}
```

Wasn't able to find a solution without a secondary function or static variables.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't need help to understand *why* this happens, only to help you come up with a suitable algorithm to get the correct solution?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Exactly..

Comment: I've tried googling it, but only incountered solutions usings additional paramters, or loops .. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Pencil. paper. Try a number between 10 and 100. Adapt the algorithm. Now try a number between 100 and 1000. Adapt.. rinse, repeat.

Comment: ...and consider another data structure. For example a string of digits.

Comment: Already did that, can't think of a way to do it without an additional parameter @joop

Comment: @sagi: If this is a pub quiz then my solution does satisfy the requirements. But I wouldn't put it in production! I'm not sure it's possible otherwise, unless you have at least one other function.

Comment: @sagi Are you allowed to have more than one function? In that case have your function call another function that takes two parameters.

Comment: How is defined reverse of 1000?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy. Please try my solution. NO LOOPS, ONE PARAMETER.

```
long GetReverse(unsigned long n)
{
    static unsigned long m = 0;
    static int recursive_level = 0;
    recursive_level++;
    if (n < 10) {
        recursive_level--;
        m = m * 10 + n;
        int temp = m;
        if (recursive_level == 0) {
            m = 0;
        }
        return temp;
    }
    m = m * 10 + (n % 10);
    GetReverse(n / 10);
    recursive_level--;
    int temp = m;
    if (recursive_level == 0) {
        m = 0;
    }
    return temp;   
 }
```

Comment: What will happen if the function will be called a second time?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow , Thx, Let's think more.

Comment: I'm not sure it's particularly simple but it does do the job, and is no worse in terms of thread safety than `rand()`. +1.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I don’t know if I’m allowed to use static variables, but I’ll upvote since it provide a good answer

Comment: Can you please confirm it works for this, 112233445566778899 ? I don't know much about C, and it seems to work in my answer but not with the code above (I get 18446744072851252147). cc @sagi

Comment: @sagi I think you might need to further clarify what's allowed in the solution. Static variables? Additional functions? C methods other than math operators (such as pow or snprintf as some of us used)? Etc. The question isn't clear :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass 2 elements to the `GetReverse` function, because the last digit will have to be shifted on the left:

```
long GetReverse(unsigned long n, unsigned long m)
{
    if (n < 10)
        return 10 * m + n;
    else
        return  GetReverse(n / 10, 10 * m + n % 10);
}
```

You can then call `GetReverse(12343, 0)` and get as expected 34321

Comment: I know how to do it with an additional element. But as I said, I have to use only one parameter

Comment: You can bypass the 2 parameter problem by creating a `GetReverse` function with 1 parameter and a `_GetReverse` function with 2 parameters. Make `GetReverse` call the recursive `_GetReverse` function.

Comment: +1, this is the only really sensible answer. In C++ you could use a default argument for `m` and it would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

This is silly and should not be used in real life, but complies with the requirements:

```
unsigned long GetReverse(unsigned long n)
{
    if (n < 10)
        return n;
    else
        return n % 10 * lround(pow(10,floor(log10(n)))) + GetReverse(n / 10);
}
```

Comment: Sadly will not always work: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452711/pow-seems-to-be-out-by-one-here

Comment: @Bathsheba It should always work since I'm `lround`ing instead of truncating.

Comment: @sagi, No need for floating-point code to solve an integer problem.

Comment: Further this still has the problem pointed out by [@Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226806/c-reverse-a-number-recursivly#comment83438389_48227832) due to its use of `floor(log10(n))`.  Should `log10(n)` return x.9999999 rather than x+1, the result is wrong.  `lround()` does not save it.

Comment: @chux To my defence I can say that at least for `10^n` there is no risk because the result will be multiplied by `0`. There is a chance of getting an invalid value for `10^n+1`, but I'm not sure if there are systems on which it will actually happen.

Comment: I'd say this is a good approach, it just needs quality `ipow10()` and `ilog10()`.  Note that OP's `long unsigned` could be 64-bit and `double` may have trouble with `n` near power-of-10 > 2**53 as the conversion from `unsigned long` to `double` is inexact.  `getReverse(99999999999999999)` failed for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that only takes one parameter, although you can only use the least significant 32 bits for your input:

```
uint64_t rev(uint64_t n)
{
    uint32_t _n = n;
    uint32_t _m = n >> 32;
    return _n < 10 
        ? 10 * _m + _n
        : rev(_n / 10 + (uint64_t)(10 * _m + _n % 10) * 65536 * 65536)
    ;
}

int main(){
    uint32_t n = 12345;
    n = rev(n);
}
```

Essentially the coefficient is stored in the higher order bits of `n`. In many ways this is a terrible contrivance since all I'm doing is using a single parameter where there should be two parameters, and I'm relying on a (well-defined) narrowing unsigned conversion at the call site! But it does show the elegance of using the fixed width unsigned types.

Comment: Not to me either, but `<< 32` causes trouble.

Comment: @unwind: On second thoughts, the intention of `_n` and `_m` is better expressed your way. Changed it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long GetReverse(unsigned long n){
    if (n < 10){
        return n;

    } else {
        unsigned long r = GetReverse(n / 10);          
        int p = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu", r);    
        return lround(pow(10, p)) * (n % 10) + r; 
    }
}

int main(void){
    unsigned long n = 112233445566778899;   
    printf("%lu", GetReverse(n));   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @sagi ah, tx. This is interesting. Are you allowed more than one function; and are you allowed math functions like, `log`, `pow`, and `lround` ? How about static variables?

Answer (score 0):

To place the last digit first you need to multiply it by 10 once for each digit in the number:

```
#include <math.h>

long GetReverse(unsigned long n)
{
    if (n < 10)
        return n;  // Removed the % 10 as it is not needed when n is < 10
    else {
        long digit = n%10;
        long factor = (long) pow(10, (int)log(n));
        return  digit * factor + GetReverse(n / 10);
    }
}
```

`log` and `pow` is used instead of loops to calculate the number of digits in `n`. Note that [this may fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452711/pow-seems-to-be-out-by-one-here) unless the implementation of `pow` is good enough. I did a test using gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) and that combination produced correct results for integer powers of 10 for results that fit in a `long`.

Comment: I think OP knows how to do with loops and additional variable so it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @achal Replaced the loop with the `log`/`pow` functions from math.h.

Comment: @Bathsheba In this case I want, no I NEED, to truncate.

Comment: The `pow` in C can undershoot for even small integer arguments.

Comment: @Bathsheba Even with an integer base? It doesn't when I try it using gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Yes it can. Due to pow(x, y) often being implemented as exp(y log x)

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452711/pow-seems-to-be-out-by-one-here

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks for the link. I've used your input to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No loops, no variables, no additional parameters!

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned long reverse(unsigned long num)
{
if (num < 10) return num;
if (num < 100) return 10 * (num %10) + reverse(num/10);
if (num < 1000) return 100 * (num %10) + reverse(num/10);
if (num < 10000) return 1000 * (num %10) + reverse(num/10);
if (num < 100000) return 10000 * (num %10) + reverse(num/10);
if (num < 1000000) return 100000 * (num %10) + reverse(num/10);
if (num < 10000000) return 1000000 * (num %10) + reverse(num/10);
if (num < 100000000) return 10000000 * (num %10) + reverse(num/10);
return 100000000 * (num %10) + reverse(num/10);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
unsigned long num, rev;

if (argc < 2) return 1;
sscanf(argv[1], "%lu", &num);

rev = reverse(num);
printf("%lu -->> %lu\n", num, rev );

return 0;
}
```

---

Or, using a helper function (**not** a variable)

[note: this has quadratic complexity(on the number of digits)]

---

```
unsigned long tencount(unsigned long num)
{
if (num < 10) return 1;
return 10 * tencount( num/10);
}

unsigned long reverse2(unsigned long num)
{
if (num < 10) return num;
return tencount(num) * (num %10) + reverse2(num/10);
}
```

Comment: It is not required to be portable. It works until it overflows. (you could check for overflow by invoking it twice, and compare the 2nd result with the original)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 32bit long you could do it without loops or recursion;

```
long GetReverse(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long x = ((n/1000000000) +
                      ((n/100000000)%10)*10 +
                      ((n/10000000)%10)*100 +
                      ((n/1000000)%10)*1000 +
                      ((n/100000)%10)*10000 +
                      ((n/10000)%10)*100000 +
                      ((n/1000)%10)*1000000 +
                      ((n/100)%10)*10000000 +
                      ((n/10)%10)*100000000 +
                      ((n)%10)*1000000000);

    return (x/(9*(x%10==0)+1)/
            (9*(x%100==0)+1)/
            (9*(x%1000==0)+1)/
            (9*(x%10000==0)+1)/
            (9*(x%100000==0)+1)/
            (9*(x%1000000==0)+1)/
            (9*(x%10000000==0)+1)/
            (9*(x%100000000==0)+1)/
            (9*(x%1000000000==0)+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
int reverse(int i) {
    static int p = 0;
    if (i==0) { int r = p; p = 0; return r; }
    p = 10*p+i%10;
    return reverse(i/10);
}
```

Idea is to use a second argument, but as it is used only to store the partial result a static variable can be used. To be able to reuse the function you just need to reset the static at the end of the recursion.

Becareful as such a function is not an involution means that `reverse(reverse(x))` not equals to `x`, think about `x=1000`. If you want involution then you need to define it over a C-string that represent the value.

Answer (score 0):

**C reverse a number recursively**

> I have an assignment to create a function that receives a number and return the reversed number.
>   No loops allowed, and the input is only the number .

Add a helper recursive function. [@Art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226806/c-reverse-a-number-recursivly/48227832?noredirect=1#comment83438478_48226806)
No static variable, no floating point math needed.

The below meets the goals:
1) Recursion used.
2) Function receives a number and return the reversed number
3) No loops allowed, and the input is only the number

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static unsigned reverse_helper(unsigned x, unsigned *pow10) {
  if (x < 10) {
    *pow10 = 10;
    return x;
  }
  unsigned y = reverse_helper(x / 10, pow10);
  y += *pow10 * (x%10);
  *pow10 *= 10;
  return y;
}

unsigned reverse(unsigned x) {
  unsigned pow10 = 1;
  unsigned y = reverse_helper(x, &pow10);
  printf("%10u %10u\n", x, y);
  return y;
}

int main(void) {
  reverse(0);
  reverse(9);
  reverse(10);
  reverse(99);
  reverse(100);
  reverse(1234);
  reverse(123456789);
}
```

Output

```
         0          0
         1          1
         9          9
        10          1
        99         99
       100          1
      1234       4321
 123456789  987654321
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution like OP's yet uses 2 recursive functions.

Recurse function with 1 parameter, no floating-point, no static variables.

```
// return the great power-of-10 less than n
unsigned long p10(unsigned long n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return 1;
  }
  return p10(n/10) * 10;
}

unsigned long GetReverse(unsigned long n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return n;
  }
  // OPs code
  //return  10 * GetReverse(n / 10) + n % 10;

  //     v----------------v------------------- scale by 1
  //     |                |   v-----------v--- scale by a power of 10 <= n
  return GetReverse(n / 10) + p10(n)*(n%10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about calling a function like `char* getReverse(int n)` So you could use mod and concatenation to obtain the reverse. Then in the caller method `int getReverse(int n)` you parse the string to int. You could use recursion and then the single line to make the parsing. No loops needed and one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my completely reentrant version, with no extra variable.  It works by using `ldiv( num / 10 )` to get quotient and remainder, then returns the remainder multiplied by 10^(num digits in quotient) added to the reverse of the quotient (code is formatted to remove the scroll bar - normally I'd have blank lines and more braces):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
/* unsigned long power function */
unsigned long lpow( unsigned long base, unsigned long exp )
{
    unsigned long result = 1UL;
    while ( exp )
    {
        if ( exp & 1 )
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }
    return( result );
}

/* count the number of decimal digits */    
unsigned long numdigits( unsigned long num )
{
    return( floor( log10( num ) ) + 1 );
}

unsigned long reverse( unsigned long in )
{
    ldiv_t tmp = ldiv( in, 10UL );
    if ( tmp.quot == 0 )
        return( tmp.rem );
    return( reverse( tmp.quot ) + tmp.rem * lpow( 10, numdigits( tmp.quot ) ) );
}
```

`unsigned long lpow()` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/101613/4756299

`unsigned long numdigits()` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068870/4756299

Called like this:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    for ( int ii = 1; ii < argc; ii++ )
    {
        unsigned long num = strtoul( argv[ ii ], NULL, 10 );

        printf( "Reverse of %lu is %lu\n", num, reverse( num ) );
    }

    return( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is unclear why the return type is declared like `long` while the parameter has the type `unsigned long`.

```
long GetReverse(unsigned long n);
^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To have a more large of integers it is better to declare the parameter and the return type like `unsigned long long int`.

The function can be defined by using a local static variable that will keep the calculated reversed value.

Here it is.

```
unsigned long long int GetReverse(unsigned long long int n)
{
    const unsigned long long int Base = 10;
    static unsigned long long int reversed;

    unsigned long long int tmp;

    reversed = Base * reversed + n % Base;

    return (n /= Base ) == 0 ? tmp = reversed, reversed = n, n = tmp, n
                             : GetReverse(n);
}
```

In the demonstrative program below there is shown how the function works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int GetReverse(unsigned long long int n)
{
    const unsigned long long int Base = 10;
    static unsigned long long int reversed;

    unsigned long long int tmp;

    reversed = Base * reversed + n % Base;

    return (n /= Base ) == 0 ? tmp = reversed, reversed = n, n = tmp, n
                             : GetReverse(n);
}

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned long long int Base = 10;

    for ( unsigned long long int i = 1, n = 0; i < Base; i++ )
    {
        n = Base * n + i;

        printf( "%llu\n", n );
        printf( "%llu\n", GetReverse( n ) );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
1

12
21

123
321

1234
4321

12345
54321

123456
654321

1234567
7654321

12345678
87654321

123456789
987654321
```