# Calculation using power function gave wrong answers for large numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, math

I have two values **p=19, q=14**. I want to calculate p<sup>q</sup> using the power function `pow(p, q)`.

Here is my code:

```
long long p=19,q=14;
cout<<pow(p,q);
```

The correct answer is: **799006685782884121** but my code gives me **799006685782884096** which is incorrect.

I have also tried doing these calculations using `unsigned long long` instead of `long long`, but this didn't help.

Comment: `pow` uses floating numbers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pow() seems to be out by one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452711/pow-seems-to-be-out-by-one-here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pow` function is defined as:

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

Which means that it takes floating point arguments and returns a floating point result. Due to the nature of floating point numbers, some numbers can not be exactly represented. The result you're getting is probably the closest match possible.

Note also that you're doing two (probably lossy) conversions:

- converting the arguments from `long long` to `double`, and
- converting the result of the function from `double` to `long long`.

Comment: still getting the same result could u please show me

Comment: @RakeshSharma if you're using MSVC then `long double` is the same as `double` which can't store all 64-bit int precisely

Comment: @RakeshSharma You were given multiple good answers. Have you read them? What is it that you still do not understand?

Comment: double can only store 54 bit, or 17 decimal digits with any accuracy.

Comment: @GemTaylor it's 53 bits and ~15-17 digits, not 54